# Create CheckBox

Tags: apex, visualforce

Please advice me to how to create checkbox.

I made a Employee Search and Delete page on visual force for practice.
And now I want to add checkbox on my search results using wrapper class. This checkbox should be  work for delete employee.

This is my VF page

```
<apex:page controller="EmployeeSHDTController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="EmployeeDelete">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!info.Employee_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!info.Employee_DOB__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!info.Employee_Mailaddress__c}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:variable id="rowIndex" var="rowIndex" value="1" />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="in">
                <apex:column headerValue="No">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!VALUE(rowIndex)}"/>
                    <apex:variable var="rowIndex" value="{!VALUE(rowIndex) + 1}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!in.Employee_Name__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="DOB">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!in.Employee_DOB__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!in.Employee_Mailaddress__c}"/>
                </apex:column>                
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:messages />
</apex:page>
```

This is my Apex

```
public class EmployeeSHDT1Controller {
    public Employee_Management__c info { get;set; }
    public List <Employee_Management__c> results { get;set; }
    
    public EmployeeSHDT1Controller(){    
        results = new List <Employee_Management__c>();
        info = new Employee_Management__c();
    }
        
    public PageReference search(){        
        String strSoqlQuery1;        
        String strSoqlQuery2;        
        String strSoqlQuery3;        
        String strSoqlQuery4;        
        String strSoqlQuery5;        
        String strSoqlQuery6;        
        String strSoqlQuery7;       
        string strEmployeeMailaddressc;        
        string strEmployeeNamec;
       
        IF(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c) && !String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c) && info.Employee_DOB__c != null) {            
            strEmployeeNamec = info.Employee_Name__c;
            strEmployeeMailaddressc = info.Employee_Mailaddress__c;
            strSoqlQuery1 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c FROM Employee_Management__c Where Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\' Or Employee_Mailaddress__c = \'' + strEmployeeMailaddressc + '\' Or Employee_DOB__c =' + String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c);
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery1);
        }
        else if(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c) && !String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c)) {            
            strEmployeeNamec = info.Employee_Name__c;
            strEmployeeMailaddressc = info.Employee_Mailaddress__c;
            strSoqlQuery2 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\' Or Employee_Mailaddress__c = \'' + strEmployeeMailaddressc + '\'';
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery2);            
        }
        else if(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c) && info.Employee_DOB__c != null) {            
            strEmployeeNamec = info.Employee_Name__c;
            strSoqlQuery3 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c WHERE Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\' Or Employee_DOB__c =' + String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c);
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery3);            
        }
        else if(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c)) {
            strEmployeeNamec = info.Employee_Name__c;
            strSoqlQuery4 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\'';
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery4);            
        }
        else if(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c) && info.Employee_DOB__c != null) {            
            strEmployeeMailaddressc = info.Employee_Mailaddress__c;
            strSoqlQuery5 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Employee_Mailaddress__c = \'' + strEmployeeMailaddressc + '\' Or Employee_DOB__c =' + String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c);
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery5);                        
        } 
        else if(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c)) {            
            strEmployeeMailaddressc = info.Employee_Mailaddress__c;
            strSoqlQuery6 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c where Employee_Mailaddress__c = \'' + strEmployeeMailaddressc + '\'';
            results = database.query(strSoqlQuery6);                        
        } 
        else if (info.Employee_DOB__c != null) {            
              strSoqlQuery7 = 'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c WHERE Employee_DOB__c = '+ String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c);
              results = database.query(strSoqlQuery7);
        } 
        else {
            ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'ERROR');
            ApexPages.addMessage(message);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public class 
    
    public class EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper {
        public Employee_Management__c Record { get;set; }
        public Boolean checked { get;set; }
        
        public EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper(Employee_Management__c c) {
            Record = record;
            checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm so sorry for my English skill is very poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you've done over 50% of the work already, it's just a matter of putting some of the pieces together.

The purpose of having the wrapper class is to give you access to a Boolean variable that you can reference/bind inside an iterable component (apex:pageBlockTable, apex:dataTable, apex:repeat). Instead of iterating over a `List<Employee_Management__c>`, you want to iterate over a `List<EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper>`.

#### So, the first change you need to make to your controller is

change this
`public List <Employee_Management__c> results { get;set; }`

to this
`public List <EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper> results { get;set; }`

#### That leads to the second change

Your `search()` method can't simply store the query results in `results` any more. You'll need to turn the individual SObject records into wrapper class instances.

The most straightforward (though not the most elegant) way to do that would be to iterate over the query results, create a new wrapper instance, and then add the wrapper to the results list.

```java
// Need to initialize the list before we can add data to it
results = new List<EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper>();

// Elsewhere in your search() method...
for(Employee_Management__c emRecord :database.query(query)){
    EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper wrapper = new EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper(emRecord);
    results.add(wrapper);
}
```

#### The final required changes are on your Visualforce page

You're iterating over `results`, but it's no longer directly working on an SObject.

`<apex:outputText value="{!in.<field name here>}"/>` won't work. You need to reference the SObject contained inside the wrapper class before you can access the fields.

The change is simple. Just use dot notation to add the SObject record.
`<apex:outputText value="{!in.Record.Employee_Name__c}"/>`

At this point, you can also add your checkbox to the pageblocktable row
`<apex:input type="checkbox" value="{!in.checked}" />`

I imagine you'll want to also add a button to call a `delete()` method which would then iterate over the results, add the records where `checked` is true to a list, and then perform a DML delete. I'll leave that work to you, and hope that you either know how to do that already or can work out what needs to be done based on my description.

#### Bonus

Your `search()` method contains a lot of repetition, and I think we can improve that.

The `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses are the same every time, it's just the filters in the `WHERE` clause that change. It also looks like whenever there are multiple filters, they're simply `OR`'d together.

I think that creating a `List<String>` to hold the filters, and then combining them with `String.join()` would work well here.

```java
public PageReference search(){
    String baseQuery = 'SELECT Id, Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  FROM Employee_Management__c WHERE {0}';

    List<String> filters = new List<String>();

    // !String.isBlank() and String.isNotBlank() do the same thing
    // I personally try to use String.isNotBlank() because I think it's easier to see
    //   the "Not" than it is to see the "!"
    if(String.isNotBlank(info.Employee_Name__c)){ filters.add('Employee_Name__c = ' +  info.Employee_Name__c); }

    if(String.isNotBlank(info.Employee_Mailaddress__c)){ filters.add('Employee_Mailaddress__c = ' +  info.Employee_Mailaddress__c); }

    if(info.Employee_DOB__c != null){ filters.add('Employee_DOB__c = ' +  String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c)); }

    results = new List<EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper>();
    
    if(filters.isEmpty()){ return null;}

    // The nice thing about String.join() is that it only adds the separator (' OR ' in this case)
    //   if it needs to be added.
    // If there's only a single filter, it will not insert the separator
    for(Employee_Management__c emRec :database.query(String.format(baseQuery, new List<Object>{String.join(filters, ' OR ')}))){
        results.add(new EmployeeSelectDeleteWrapper(emRec));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm going to try to solve my problem based on your advice.